# Why not a balanced tree when fork is inside a loop?

Tags: c, ubuntu, fork

consider a following code

```
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
  {
     int pid=fork();
     if(pid==0)
       {
         printf("\nI am  child %d\n",i)
       }
      else
       {
         wait();
         printf("\n I am  parent %d\n",i)

       }
  }
```

**Output**

I am child 1

I am child 2

I am child 3

I am parent 3

I am parent 2

I am child 3

I am parent 3

I am parent 1

I am child 2

I am child 3

I am parent 3

I am parent 2

I am child 3

I am parent 3

So my observation is that output would always be a balance tree with 2^4-2 output and this would always be a balanced tree using following observation

First parent fork creating a child then child fork creating a child so child is creating it's child until no loop terminates.
Then at the very depth child prints i then it's sibling parent and we go upward printing each sibling parent.

Am I right in my observation?

**Change in Code**

```
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
      {
         int pid=fork();
         printf("\nvalue of i is %d",i)
      }
```

**Output**

value of i is 1

value of i is 2

value of i is 3
naseer@naseer-khan:~$ 
value of i is 3

value of i is 2

value of i is 3

value of i is 1

value of i is 2

value of i is 3

value of i is 3

value of i is 3

value of i is 2

value of i is 3

value of i is 3

naseer@naseer-khan:~$

Can somebody explain me what is happening now and even command prompt is getting displayed in some iterations?

Comment: But I used wait inside my parent.

Comment: But your parent `printf` is before the `wait`

Comment: Please update your output as well. It should be different now.

Comment: @PSkocik when I removed wait and if else block and entered a simple printf statement printing i.The output was very weird.I mean I am not getting what is happening inside a loop when fork is there?

Comment: Don't remove the `wait`. With the `wait` there and the `printf` in the right place now you should get the expected output. Please update the output run from the new code.